# ST2- Adding custom directory for Auto Completion (SublimeRope)

Tags: python, sublimetext2, rope, sublimerope

http://sublimerope.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cache_mechanisms.html

I want to add a custom directory from where I want auto completion. `The Old Way` mentioned on the above page does that job with `prefs.add('python_path', '/home/abc/custom/')`
, but the page says it's not recommended.

How can I do add a custom directory (say `/home/abc/custom/`) with the newer way mentioned on the page? It only explains how to add modules not directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you should already have defined folders in your [project settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html). It looks like SublimeRope looks in those folders automatically, and you just define the modules you want to be included.

If you haven't already, I recommend taking a look at [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) as well. I'm not terribly familiar with SublimeRope, but SCI is quite useful for my Python coding needs.